# WPF ListView animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make ListViewItem which would increase after button click. But I have some problem when animation start's increasing it's overlap nearest items.
How can it be solved?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.27"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1.562"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="6.75"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="5.625"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding .}"></Label>
                <Button Grid.Column="1"  Content="{Binding .}" Width="40">
                                                    <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"></BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Problem is in ListViewItem size, because it doesn't change?

Comment: Use `LayoutTransform` instead.